# Finding shape of image within another image

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I'm trying to determine the best way of finding the position of a shape within an image.
I have an image of a puzzle piece with a white outline.

I need to somehow find this same white outline in another given image, and be able to output the position of the bounding box.

What would be best way of doing this? OpenCV, emgucv, ML?

Ex. puzzle piece
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCrAK.jpg

Thanks

Comment: can you share the images.?

Comment: Added example piece

Answer (score 0):

For my answer I assumed that the other pieces you want to detect will have the **exact** same white outline as the example piece given. I just used the find contours method in emgucv to get the outline of the puzzle piece.

```
//Read in the image
Mat puzzlePiece = CvInvoke.Imread("Puzzle\Piece\path", ImreadModes.AnyColor);

//Create a grayscale version of the image
Mat puzzlePieceGray = new Mat();
CvInvoke.CvtColor(puzzlePiece, puzzlePieceGray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

//Black image to draw contours on
Image<Bgr, byte> output = new Image<Bgr, byte>(puzzlePiece.Width, puzzlePiece.Height, 
    new Bgr(Color.Black));

VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

//Find and draw the found contours
CvInvoke.FindContours(puzzlePieceGray, contours, null, RetrType.External, 
    ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
CvInvoke.DrawContours(output, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));

//Display the found contours
CvInvoke.Imshow("Contours Drawn", output);
CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);
```

The Original Image

[image]

The Image with Contours

[image]

Since there is only the input image that you have provided, I cant compare the size of the contour to other pieces, but here is some sample code of how it could work.

```
if (contours[0].Size == contoursTwo[0].Size)
{
    //do stuff
}
```